# Search for proper column and find duplicates - macro amendment needed [VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA Macro for excel to find duplicates. It works but it is specified to a certain column. I would like to search through column headers which are in the 1st row and find the header called "Email" (the best would be "Email*" as sometimes this header contains some other words after the "Email" word). I think this script doesn't adjust to the number of rows and it is limited to 65536 values. I would prefer to let this script adjust to the number of values in the column. I have a similar VBA macro which does the perfect job. I thought I would be able to use this macro as an example and amend the one which I am currently working on...however I failed. Could anyone help me to do the proper amendments to the first code?

**VBA MACRO WHICH I WOULD LIKE TO AMEND:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteDups()

Dim x As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Sheets("test").Activate
LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & x), Range("A" & x).Text) > 1 Then
        Range("A" & x).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 48, 48)
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

**VBA MACRO WHICH WORKS FINE AND I WANTED TO USE AS AN EXAMPLE:**

```
Function getAllColNum(ByVal rowNum As Long, ByVal searchString As Variant) As Object
Dim allColNum As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim width As Long
Set allColNum = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
colNum = 1
With ActiveSheet
    width = .Cells(rowNum, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For i = 1 To width
         If InStr(UCase(Trim(.Cells(rowNum, i).Value)), UCase(Trim(searchString))) > 0 Then
             allColNum.Add i, ""
         End If '
    Next i
End With
Set getAllColNum = allColNum
End Function



Sub GOOD_WORKS_No_Dots_at_End_of_Emails()
Dim strSearch As String
strSearch = "Email"
Dim colNum As Variant
Dim allColNum As Object
Sheets("Data").Activate
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Set allColNum = getAllColNum(1, searchString)
For Each colNum In allColNum
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
        With Range(Cells(i, colNum), Cells(i, colNum))
            If Right(.Value, 1) = "." Then .Value = Left(.Value, Len(.Value) - 1)
        End With
    Next i
Next colNum
Sheets("Automation").Activate
MsgBox "No Dots at the end of email addresses - Done!"
End Sub
```

**MY WORK SO FAR**

```
Function getAllColNum(ByVal rowNum As Long, ByVal searchString As Variant) As Object
Dim allColNum As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim width As Long
Set allColNum = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
colNum = 1
With ActiveSheet
width = .Cells(rowNum, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To width
     If UCase(Trim(.Cells(rowNum, i).Value)) Like UCase(Trim(searchString)) Then
         allColNum.Add i, ""
     End If '
Next i
End With
Set getAllColNum = allColNum
End Function



Sub testing_testing()
Dim strSearch As String
strSearch = "Email"
Dim colNum As Variant
Dim allColNum As Object
Sheets("Data").Activate
Dim LR As Long, i As Long
Set allColNum = getAllColNum(1, searchString)
For Each colNum In allColNum
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, colNum).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To LR
    With Range(Cells(i, colNum), Cells(i, colNum))
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("R1:A" & x), Range("R" & x).Text) > 1 Then
    Range("A" & x).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 48, 48)
    End With
    End If
Next i
Next colNum
Sheets("Automation").Activate
MsgBox "Finiding duplicates - Done!"
End Sub
```

---

Seems to be more complicated and as I mentioned I have limited knowledge of VBA. However, I found a different script which might be easier to amend.

This macro finds the email address column and marks the whole column

```
Option Explicit

Sub GOOD_WORKS_Mark_Email_Duplicates()

Dim x As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Sheets("test").Activate
LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & x), Range("A" & x).Text) > 1 Then
        Range("A" & x).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 48, 48)
    End If
Next x
MsgBox "Email duplicates has been marked - red cells. Check if there are any red cells in the Email column"
End Sub
```

This one finds duplicates using countif function (which is good to me. The only problem is that I have this macro as a button, where the range is specified

```
Sub Highlight_Duplicates(Values As Range)
Dim Cell

For Each Cell In Values
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Values, Cell.Value) > 1 Then
    Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End If

Next Cell
End Sub
```

Then the action button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Highlight_Duplicates (Sheets("Test").Range("C2:C92"))

End Sub
```

It is fine for me to run 1st macro and then the 2nd. However, I don't know how to get rid of Range in the action button. Any ideas?

Comment: "However I failed" - so, what goes wrong? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

In your getAllColNum function, change this:

```
If InStr(UCase(Trim(.Cells(rowNum, i).Value)), _
         UCase(Trim(searchString))) > 0 Then
```

to this:

```
If UCase(Trim(.Cells(rowNum, i).Value)) Like UCase(Trim(searchString)) Then
```

and that will allow you to pass a wildcard header like "*email*" and get all matching columns.

Comment: Hi Tim, I added this phrase proposed by you. But I have limited knowledge of VBA so I think I did something wrong as I got error. After I replaced getAllColNum I went to LastRow Range and replace references to A column into strSearch. What I did wrong?

Comment: Update your question with your current code - otherwise it's hard to guess what the issue is. And if you get errors, state exactly what the error message is.

Comment: I editet my previous post and at the bottom I attached my code (Under MY WORK SO FAR). Despite the fact it doesn't work I don't know how should I get rid of defining specific column (as now with my script it looks at column R) - that's why I want to identify the column.

Comment: First thing - add Option Explicit to the top of your code module. You're calling `Set allColNum = getAllColNum(1, searchString)`, but a few lines a bove you have `strSearch = "Email"` - you need to use the correct variable (and "\*Email\*" if you want to search your column headers using wildcards)